# Can you safely compare two floats by rounding them in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point, epsilon

Rather than using an epsilon for float comparison, can you reliably compare two floats for equivalency by rounding them to the desired precision?

For example:

```
round($float, 3) === round($otherFloat, 3)
```

Comment: if your ok compering, round(float), and not the original float, then its fine

Comment: That is what I am asking. For the record, I didn't ask how should I compare floating point numbers, this is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If your numbers are just barely on opposite sides of the value where the function will round up instead of down (a half-integer if you're round to the nearest integer), then they will round to different numbers no matter how close together they are.

Comment: Good point, but am I correct in assuming that would only matter if I was rounding to a very high precision?